# Laravel Livewire, prevent selection lists from scrolling up on update

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel Livewire. I'm intrigued by it's concept, but it's also quite confusing in certain specific situations. I am trying to make a selection list that comes up as a modal like so:

This is the "parent" template:

```php
<x-slot name="breadcrumbs">
    @include('breadcrumbs', [ 'path' => ['roles' => __('messages.roles')]])
</x-slot>

<div class="py-12">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <x-jet-action-message class="mr-3" on="created">
        {{ __('messages.created_role') }}
        </x-jet-action-message>
        <div class="sm:flex sm:items-center">
            <div class="sm:flex-auto">
                <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-700">{{ __('messages.all_roles_in_system') }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-16 sm:flex-none">
                <a href="#" wire:click="$emitTo('roles.add-role-form', 'showForm')" class="button inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-joij-green-600 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-joij-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-joij-green-500 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:w-auto">
                    {{ __('messages.add_role') }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <livewire:roles.add-role-form />
        <livewire:roles.role-list />
    </div>
</div>
```

The `role-list` looks like this:

```php
<div class="mt-8 flex flex-col">
    <div class="-my-2 -mx-4 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
        <div class="inline-block min-w-full py-2 align-middle md:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="overflow-hidden shadow ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 md:rounded-lg">
                <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-300">
                    <thead class="bg-gray-50">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="py-3.5 pl-4 pr-3 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">
                                <a href="#" class="group inline-flex">
                                    {{__('messages.name')}}
                                    <span class="invisible ml-2 flex-none rounded text-gray-400 group-hover:visible group-focus:visible">
                                        <svg class="h-5 w-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                                        </svg>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="relative py-3.5 pl-3 pr-4 sm:pr-6">
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="divide-y divide-gray-200 bg-white">
                        @foreach ($roles as $role)
                        <tr class="{{ $role->uuid === $activeRole ? 'bg-joij-green-200' : 'bg-white' }}" wire:key="key-{{ $role->uuid  }}">
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium {{ $role->uuid === $activeRole ? 'text-white' : 'text-gray-900' }} sm:pl-6">{{ $role->name }}</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <button wire:click="toggleActiveRole('{{ $role->uuid }}')" type="button" class="inline-flex items-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium leading-4 text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-joij-green-500 focus:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-30">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-3 h-3">
                                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M16.862 4.487l1.687-1.688a1.875 1.875 0 112.652 2.652L10.582 16.07a4.5 4.5 0 01-1.897 1.13L6 18l.8-2.685a4.5 4.5 0 011.13-1.897l8.932-8.931zm0 0L19.5 7.125M18 14v4.75A2.25 2.25 0 0115.75 21H5.25A2.25 2.25 0 013 18.75V8.25A2.25 2.25 0 015.25 6H10" />
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium leading-4 text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-joij-green-500 focus:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-30">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-3 h-3">
                                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M14.74 9l-.346 9m-4.788 0L9.26 9m9.968-3.21c.342.052.682.107 1.022.166m-1.022-.165L18.16 19.673a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244 2.077H8.084a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244-2.077L4.772 5.79m14.456 0a48.108 48.108 0 00-3.478-.397m-12 .562c.34-.059.68-.114 1.022-.165m0 0a48.11 48.11 0 013.478-.397m7.5 0v-.916c0-1.18-.91-2.164-2.09-2.201a51.964 51.964 0 00-3.32 0c-1.18.037-2.09 1.022-2.09 2.201v.916m7.5 0a48.667 48.667 0 00-7.5 0" />
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @if ($role->uuid === $activeRole)
                        <tr wire:key="sub-{{ $role->uuid  }}">
                            <td colspan="2" class="relative mb-0 pb-0">
                                <livewire:roles.permission-list wire:key="$role->uuid" :role="$role" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then I have the `permission-list`:

```php
<table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-300 bg-gray-50">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-gray-100">
            <th scope="col" class="py-3.5 pl-6 pr-3 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Permissions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($role->permissions()->get() as $permission)
        <tr>
            <td class="px-6 py-2 text-sm text-gray-500 lg:table-cell">{{ $permission->identifier }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        <tr>
            <td class="px-6 py-3.5 text-sm text-gray-500 lg:table-cell">
                <livewire:roles.permission-dropdown :role="$role" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then the `permission-dropdown`:

```php
<div>
    <button
        type="button" wire:click="togglePermissionList"
        class="relative cursor-default rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left shadow-sm {{ $showPermissionList ? 'bg-joij-green-500 text-white border-joij-green-500 outline-none ring-1 ring-joij-green-500 ': 'hover:bg-joij-green-100 hover:text-gray-800 ' }}sm:text-sm"
        aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="listbox-label">
        <span class="flex items-center">
            <span class="block truncate">{{__('messages.add_permissions')}}</span>
        </span>
        <span class="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5"
                 stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12 6v12m6-6H6"/>
            </svg>
        </span>
    </button>
    @if ($showPermissionList)
    <div class="fixed top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 drop-shadow-md bg-white min-h-[400px] max-h-[650px] ring-1 ring-gray-300 rounded-md w-96 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
        <ul wire:key="key-{{ time() }}"
            class="absolute left-0 top-0 right-0 bottom-14 overflow-auto text-base border-b border-opacity-50"
            tabindex="-1">
            @foreach ($permissions as $detailedPermission)
            <li wire:click="toggleSelectPermission('{{ $detailedPermission->uuid }}')"
                wire:key="key-{{ $detailedPermission->uuid }}"
                class="text-gray-900 relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-3 pr-9 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:cursor-pointer block"
                role="option"
            >
                <div class="flex items-center">
                    <span class="inline-block h-2 w-2 flex-shrink-0 rounded-full {{ $detailedPermission->selected ? 'bg-joij-green-100' : 'bg-gray-200' }}"
                    aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="font-normal ml-3 block truncate">{{ $detailedPermission->identifier }}</span>
                </div>
                @if ($detailedPermission->selected)
                <span class="text-joij-green-600 absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4">
                    <svg class="h-5 w-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor"
                         aria-hidden="true">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M16.704 4.153a.75.75 0 01.143 1.052l-8 10.5a.75.75 0 01-1.127.075l-4.5-4.5a.75.75 0 011.06-1.06l3.894 3.893 7.48-9.817a.75.75 0 011.05-.143z"
                              clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                @endif
            </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
        <button
            type="button"
            wire:click="togglePermissionList"
            class="absolute bottom-2 right-2 cursor-default rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left shadow-sm bg-joij-green-500 text-white border-joij-green-500 outline-none ring-1 ring-joij-green-500 sm:text-sm"
            aria-haspopup="listbox"
            aria-expanded="true"
            aria-labelledby="listbox-label"
        >
            <span class="flex items-center">
                <span class="block truncate">Close</span>
            </span>
            <span class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                </svg>
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

If I click the `<li>`. The  `wire:click="toggleSelectPermission('{{ $detailedPermission->uuid }}')` . Is called to assign this permission to a role. This works! But the list will scroll up on every selection making this into an unusable solution. Is there something I can do to prevent the list from scrolling back up again?

Comment: maybe try using wire:click.prevent or wire:click.stop, maybe it will stop the scroll

Comment: when the role is assigned, what position do you expect to have on the select? you have 2 selects right?(permission and role)

Comment: I expect livewire to refresh the element that is selected (changes a visual aspect to look like it's selected) But the scroll position of the whole list (that scrolls in it's parent) should not be jumping back to the initial scroll position.

Comment: I tried your suggestions (wire:click.prevent and wire:click.stop) but it still refreshes the whole thing so it will jump up.

Comment: you are using the default select of html? like you are not using select2 right?(because select2 will create an entire DOM just for the select), either way did you try adding wire:ignore on the div parent?(where the select is located)

Comment: livewire will ignore that block, and maybe the refresh will not be a problem

Comment: if you add ddd($detailedPermission->uuid) after the conditional     @if($showPermissionList), what value it returns? i assume that $detailedPermission is an object, so did you try on livewire inside the function toggleSelectPermission, use ddd($detailedPermission) ? ddd acts like a debuger, just in case you didn't know

Comment: I put wire:click.prevent or stop on the "ul" that has the overflow-auto class, it's still jumping back. Will try the debug thing now.

Comment: I added the {{ ddd() }} thing afther the foreach, it's simply outputting the uuids. Which is expected. All of them have a uuid.

Comment: Right now it seems to be random. Sometimes it jumps up, other times it doesn't. This randomness is something I'm noticing with Livewire a lot btw. I'm not sure if I'm making a fundamental mistake in the way I use it, or it's just fundamentally broken.